# Angular4 mandatory Input on component

Tags: angular

I've a component with the following input

```
@Input() id: string
```

I would like this input to be mandatory, which means that if I call my component without specifying it, it would throw a js error.

I can do it in the `ngOnInit`, but I imagine there is a keyword for this ?

Comment: There is no keyword. If you want it to be required then `ngOnInit` would be the best place to do a check and throw an error if it is not supplied.

Comment: Or you can give it a default value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw error in ngOnInit method after checking input property:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!id) {
      throw new Error('No ID provided!');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### The possible solution is:-

```
    @Input() id: string;

    ngOnInit(){

// 'id' will be 'undefined' so provide a default data when component loads individually, so possible solution below

    if(!id){     
    this.id = '.......';
    /*---------Other Implementation-------------*/
    }

    }
```